# Additional credit card with different limit on same account?

Tags: united-states, credit-card

Does anyone know of a way to get another credit card for an authorized user but with a much lower credit limit?  I'd like to use my existing credit card account but I don't really see a way to do this.  Another number basically means another account.

I don't want a debit card.  It's almost like I need to open a new credit card account with a small limit and add the other person to it.

Any one have some other ideas how this might work?

Comment: American Express lets you set spending limits for the other authorized buyers on your account. Would that work for you?

Comment: Why are you opposed to a debit card?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into getting a business credit card. When I had my Chase business credit card, I could add authorized users to the main account and set a spending limit on each card.

Answer (score 0):

Generally not.  Since authorized user cards are the same account and the difference between the two (the original and the AU card) are minimal.

Note, there's nothing technically stopping banks from offering this as a feature, two cards do have identifiers that indicate they're separate cards, but the banks concern for your needs stops at how much they can bleed from you, and "helping you control your spending" is not part of that.

Answer (score 0):

As of Sept 2021

Following consumer cards allow setting spending limits for authorized users

- American Express
- Capital One

Following consumer cards DO NOT allow setting spending limits for authorized users

- Citibank (Except for Costco branded)
- Bank of America
- Chase